# How does Hazoret's Undying Fury work with Aftermath cards?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I cast [Hazoret's Undying Fury](http://www.magicspoiler.com/mtg-spoiler/hazorets-undying-fury/), and of the four exiled cards, one of them is [Appeal//Authority](http://www.magicspoiler.com/mtg-spoiler/appeal-authority/), which, according to the April rules change, now has a CMC of 3. I cast Appeal, placing it in my graveyard at resolution.* Can I now also cast Authority for free? The Gatherer rulings on this don't seem that clear to me. If it has a combined set of characteristics in any zone except the stack, then would Hazoret's Undying Fury see both halves as valid free casts? When Appeal//Authority moves from exile to the graveyard, does the zone change cause Hazoret's Undying Fury to see the card as a different object?

*Note that I'm not asking whether the Aftermath half of a card can be cast from exile. It's clear in the Aftermath reminder text that it can't:

> (Cast this spell only from your graveyard. Then exile it.)

This is specifically asking whether after resolving the top half of an Aftermath card using Hazoret's Undying Fury a player could cast the Aftermath half from their graveyard for free.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You can't cast Authority from the graveyard for free.**

Appeal//Authority is not in the graveyard when you are instructed to cast the cards Undying Fury exiled. If you haven't cast Appeal, it's in exile. If you have cast Appeal, it's on the stack.

Keep in mind that Undying Fury only has you cast spells (which is to place it on the stack, make some choices, and pay its costs). They don't resolve immediately. The spell will only resolve when it's the top item on the stack after all players have passed priority in sequence, which can't happen before Undying Fury has finished resolving.

The only way Appeal//Authority could be present in the graveyard when Undying Fury instructs you to cast it is if some replacement effect caused Undying Fury to place the card in the graveyard instead of in exile. This effect would be phrased "*If a card would be exiled, put it in the graveyard instead.*" If such an effect existed and was applied, then you could cast either Appeal or Authority for free (but not both) since Undying Fury is the one that put it in the graveyard.<sup>[CR 400.7][CR 400.7h]</sup>

**You can't cast Authority from exile.**

Undying Fury could cast Authority from exile, except Aftermath forbids Authority from being "cast from any zone other than a graveyard",<sup>[CR 702.126a]</sup> and restrictions take priority over instructions.<sup>[CR 101.2]</sup>

**You can't cast Authority from the stack.**

Casting Appeal places the card on the stack. At this point, the Appeal//Authority card that Undying Fury exiled no longer exists as far as Undying Fury is concerned.<sup>[CR 400.7]</sup>

---

> 101.2. When a rule or effect allows or directs something to happen, and another effect states that it can’t happen, the “can’t” effect takes precedence.
>
> *Example: If one effect reads “You may play an additional land this turn” and another reads “You can’t play land cards this turn,” the effect that precludes you from playing lands wins.*
>
> 400.7. An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence. There are nine exceptions to this rule:
>
> 400.7h If an effect causes an object to move to a public zone, other parts of that effect can find that object. If the cost of a spell or ability causes an object to move to a public zone, that spell or ability’s effects can find that object.
>
> 702.126a Aftermath is an ability found on some split cards (see rule 708, “Split Cards”). It represents three static abilities. “Aftermath” means “You may cast this half of this split card from your graveyard,” “This half of this split card can’t be cast from any zone other than a graveyard,” and “If this spell was cast from a graveyard, exile it instead of putting it anywhere else any time it would leave the stack.”

Comment: Thanks for the edit on my answer @ikegami, just for my own reference where do you pull your rules quotes from? Also how quick are they with updating the rules for new set mechanics, especially for mechanics that have only been spoiled and not yet printed?

Comment: I google "MTG rules" to get to [the official page](http://magic.wizards.com/en/game-info/gameplay/rules-and-formats/rules). I don't know how far in advance of them coming into effect (if at all) they are updated.

Comment: @Malco As a rule, the official rules are not updated to reference a new set's mechanics until some time after the complete official spoiler for that set is released. Specifically, sometime after spoilers are completed, Wizards posts an article on their website listing the rule changes that will go into effect with that set's release, and sometime between that and the prerelease, the rules PDF files are updated. I don't know exactly when it is, either, but there's not a long window between the release of the rules updates and the release of the cards.

Comment: @ikegami I see, thanks. I had forgotten that Aftermath was introduced in Amonkhet so I thought you had some sort of special site that had the rules early, hahaha.

Comment: @Malco The full rules are usually posted by a set's release date, though occasionally they are a little late, especially for larger updates. However they also usually have the CR entries for new abilities in the Mechanics of X articles that come out around when previews start.

Answer (score 3):

*This will probably be something that will end up being covered in the special rulings once the cards are actually announced but I will do my best on explaining the probable course of action.*

**Part 1: Can you choose to cast Authority *before* it enters the graveyard?**

You would not be able to cast [Authority](http://www.magicspoiler.com/mtg-spoiler/appeal-authority/) for free with [Hazorets's Undying Fury](http://www.magicspoiler.com/mtg-spoiler/hazorets-undying-fury/). Aftermath represents three static abilities including:

> This half of this split card can’t be cast from any zone other than a graveyard

So you would not be able to cast Authority at all with Hazoret's Undying Fury.

**Part 2: Can you choose to cast Authority *after* it enters the graveyard?**

At the very least by the time [Appeal//Authority](http://www.magicspoiler.com/mtg-spoiler/appeal-authority/) has entered your graveyard Hazoret's Undying Fury will have already finished resolving so it won't be a valid card to choose from. This is in addition to the fact that Hazoret's Undying Fury is not looking to cast anything from the graveyard in the first place.

Comment: Careful with the wording in this answer. Hazoret's Undying Fury does not have any targets.

Comment: @eyeballfrog correct, answer has been updated.

Answer (score 3):

There's one other reason you can't do this - one I consider to be a fairly important reason - which is that Hazoret's Undying Fury ("HUF") only lets you cast any of the exiled cards *immediately*. Any card among the four that you don't choose to cast at that point stays exiled, and any of the cards you *do* choose to cast goes on the stack just as if you'd cast it from your hand. Once that happens, HUF's effect is *done*. It does not allow you to do anything you couldn't ordinarily do with those cards at any later time in the game. (Such as casting the aftermath half from the graveyard for free.)

You can compare something like [Bring To Light](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBring%20To%20Light%5d), which also exiles a card and gives you a one-time choice of whether to cast it without paying its mana cost. While the Gatherer rulings don't specifically detail its interaction with aftermath cards, they do make a point that you don't get a choice to cast it later in the turn.

Comment: This answer isn't really correct. Even if Hazoret's Undying Fury *didn't* restrict you to casting the cards immediately, you still wouldn't be able to cast the Aftermath halves of cards with it. Cards that do allow you to cast the card later, like Mind's Desire, still only let you cast the card exiled with it from exile. Once you cast the spell and it moves to the graveyard, it's a different object and Mind's Desire's effect no longer applies to it.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I don't think your comment is accurate. There are multiple reasons you can't do what the OP is asking about, and what I've identified in my answer is definitely one of them. I don't mention the other reasons (because other answers have already done so), but that doesn't make my answer _incorrect_, only incomplete (again, intentionally so). Perhaps I shouldn't call this the "main reason", though.

Comment: I'm telling you, the "reason" you gave doesn't make a difference with regards to the original question. The fact that you can only cast the spells immediately has *no bearing* on whether you can cast spells with Aftermath.

Comment: And I'm claiming otherwise: that the reason I gave _does_ make a difference with regard to the original question. This reason is every bit as effective at making it impossible to cast the Aftermath card for free as the reason that it's a different object.

Comment: How does it make a difference? In what way does the fact that the spells are cast immediately have any bearing on whether you can cast Aftermath spells? I already pointed out that you can't cast Aftermath spells with a similar effect that does not have that restriction. And there are effect that allow you to cast spells from the graveyard, and those allow you to cast Aftermath spells, even if you can only cast the spell immediately.

Comment: It sounds like you're making a "straw man" argument: this question is not about casting aftermath spells in general. This question is about casting the _specific_ aftermath spell whose non-aftermath half was already cast (and resolved), using the same effect that allowed you to cast the non-aftermath half.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61338/discussion-between-murgatroid99-and-david-z).

Comment: Unlike @murgatroid99, I believe you are right and that the the main/primary reason it can't be cast from the graveyard is that it's not in the graveyard. In fact, if a replacement effect caused it to be in the graveyard instead of exile, 400.7 would be defeated by 400.7h, so 400.7 never applies. I have revised my answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, since by the time Appeal is done, so is Hazoret's Fury.

As part of resolving Fury, you put the spell(s) on the stack.  Then Fury is done.  Then the spell(s) resolve.

At that point, Appeal//Authority is in the graveyard, and since Fury is done, you can't cast Authority for free.